# Is there an autocmd event that triggers when a command becomes available?

Tags: neovim, autocmd, lua, lsp, pyright

I'm using `nvim-lsp` and `pyright`. That latter provides a command `PyrightSetPythonPath` to reset the path to the python interpreter. Since I can see no other way to perform the same task, I'd like to call this command **whenever it becomes available**.

**NB** `LspAttach` does not work since `PyrightSetPythonPath` seems to only become available a bit later after LSP attaching.

```lua
local callback = function ()
    if vim.fn.exists ':PyrightSetPythonPath' == 2 then
        local wherepython = (function ()
            local f = io.popen('where python')
            local where = f:read()
            f:close()
            return where
        end)()

        vim.cmd.PyrightSetPythonPath(wherepython)
    end
end

local pyright_group = vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('pyright_set_path', {})
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('LspAttach', { callback = callback
                                         , pattern = '*.py'
                                         , group = pyright_group
                                         })
-- does not work
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t use nvim-lsp, but if you look at the [source](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/lua/lspconfig/server_configurations/pyright.lua#L27), you’ll see that you should be able to set `config.settings.python.pythonPath` the same as you do with the rest of your configuration.

Besides that, there is the `CmdUndefined` and `FuncUndefined` autocommands that lazy load specific commands until they are actually used. I don’t know if it would help in this situation.

Lastly, maybe try using `vim.schedule` or `vim.schedule_wrap` in your callback to see if that will get it to work if neither of the things above do. You could also try removing the lazy-loading of your plugin if that is what you’re doing as well.